# Dynamic height in custom header image panel

Tags: headers

I've enabled the custom header image panel for my theme.. That all works fine, but it has a predetermined height. How can i make it dynamic? The width can be permanent.

I used this code.
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-enable-custom-header-images-panel-in-wordpress-3-0/

```
define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', apply_filters( 'yourtheme_header_image_width', 940 ) );
define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', apply_filters( 'yourtheme_header_image_height',  198 ) );

set_post_thumbnail_size( HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT, true );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `apply_filters` you can use `yourtheme_header_image_height` filter  hook to change the height:

```
add_filter('yourtheme_header_image_height','dynamic_height');
function dynamic_height($height){
   $custom_height = get_option('dynamic_header_height');
   return $custom_height;
}
```